# How can I catch Codeigniter multiple file upload error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm using Codeigniter for uploading files. It's working fine when I meet the file requirements. The problem is, I want to display the errors if ever there is one, but my page only refreshes when there is an error. Here is my code (I only got the code from the web and revised it):

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key=>$val)
{
  $i = 1;
  foreach($val as $v)
  {
   $field_name = "file_".$i;
   $_FILES[$field_name][$key] = $v;
   $i++;   
  }
}
 $err = 0;
 $i=0;
 // Unset the useless one ;)
 unset($_FILES['userfile']);
 $config['file_name'] = time();
 $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/events';
 $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
 $config['max_size'] = '200000';
 $this->load->library('upload',$config);
 foreach($_FILES as $field_name => $file)
 {
  if ($this->upload->do_upload($field_name))
  {
   $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //UPLOAD FILES TO FOLDER
   $this->Upload_items->files($upload_data['file_name']); //WRITE TO DATABASE;
  }else{
   echo $this->upload->display_errors();
  }
  $i++;
  if(($i==$ctr)&&($err==0)){
   $this->Upload_items->event(); //WRITE TO MULTIMEDIA TABLE
  }
 }
```

The functions to write to the database are not yet done, btw.

EDIT: The error for allowed_types is displaying, but the error for exceeding file size is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $config ['upload_path'] = 'upload/Main_category_product/';
    $path = $config ['upload_path'];
    $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config ['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config ['max_width'] = '1920';
    $config ['max_height'] = '1280';
    $this->load->library ( 'upload', $config );

    foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value ) {

        if (! empty ( $value ['tmp_name'] ) && $value ['size'] > 0) {

            if (! $this->upload->do_upload ( $key )) {

                $errors = $this->upload->display_errors ();
                flashMsg ( $errors );
            } else {
                // Code After Files Upload Success GOES HERE
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the FlashMSG function send the messages right time to the users. OR collect all messages in a array and display in the end.